# Cassandra/Hector = How to get and compile ORM without using Maven and/or GIT from GitHub

Tags: git, github, cassandra, hector

I neither use Maven nor Git. And using the download link provided by GIThub does provide a a Zipped Archive of Hector: https://github.com/rantav/hector/archives/1d6f0ba689416b81ddd2f3d0ba61a9e3c8d23a0d respectively https://github.com/downloads/rantav/hector/hector-core-0.7.0-29.tgz

But this zip archive strangely does NOT include the "object-mapper" directory that can be seen here:
https://github.com/rantav/hector/

(only the core directory is included in the downloadable zip).

What is the easiest way to get the "object-mapper" classes compiled so that I can use them in my programm.

Thanks very much
Jens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second download link is provided by the author, not GitHub.

When you download via the big button on the top, you are downloading the actual source. When you download from one of the links the author provides, you download a premade tarball of the source.

Try this link: https://github.com/rantav/hector/zipball/master

Comment: Thanks very much. Thats a good learning, that those links are all different. I thought they are automatically created and always downloaded the package from the author, rather the sources. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Per Blender's answer, since the project is maintained at github, https://github.com/rantav/hector/zipball/master is definitely the way to go.

However, even if you don't use Maven, you can still grab releases of all kinds of stuff from Maven central at http://search.maven.org/.

For instance, as of writing the latest release of hector-core is 0.7.0-29 and it's available here: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|me.prettyprint|hector-core|0.7.0-29|bundle

Clicking the [me.prettyprint](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1022875183) link on that page will show you other artifacts that are available for this group id.  By doing so you'll find out that the object mapper is available under the artifact [hector-object-mapper](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1797676909)